# Lee solo líneas pares

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con este código en Java, lo que pasa es que intento abrir un archivo de texto con varias líneas de código pero al abrirlo solo lee ciertas líneas del archivo en lugar de abrirlo completo, no encuentro porque es el error.

```
public class archivos {

    private File archivo;
    private FileReader archivoLector;
    private BufferedReader buferLector;
    private String linea;

    public archivos(String direccion) {
        archivo = new File(direccion);
        try {
            archivoLector = new FileReader(archivo);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
            System.out.println("error.getMessage()");
        }
        buferLector = new BufferedReader(archivoLector);
    }

    public String leerLinea() throws IOException {
        while (buferLector.ready()) {
            if (!(linea = buferLector.readLine()).equals("\000")) {
                return linea;
            }
        }
        buferLector.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Al abrirlo lo hago de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    archivos archivo = new archivos("acciones.txt");
    String area;
    while (archivo.leerLinea() != null) {
        area = archivo.leerLinea();
        System.out.println(area);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo `leerLinea()` solo se debe llamar una vez por ciclo, en tu caso lo hace en la condicion del while y dentro de este. La solucion seria q lo hicieras asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    archivos archivo = new archivos("acciones.txt");
    String area;
    while ((area=archivo.leerLinea()) != null) {
        System.out.println(area);
    }
}
```